# How to slice a text file into several files of 100 lines each?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

My question might be quite unclear here.
I have a giant text file with values that looks like this

```
0.00601233
0.000139403
0.000133679
0.000139497
0.000141683
0.000141888
0.000138646
0.000133465
0.000146326
0.000135611
...
```

And I want to slice it into several files of 100 lines.

File `1` will have lines 1 to 100.

File `2` will have lines 101 to 200.

etc...

There's probably a way to do this using `sed` or `awk` but I'm not familiar enough with theses tools or with regular expressions to do what I want here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [`split` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/split.html):

```
split -l 100 file
```

By default `split` makes output files `xaa`, `xab`, and so on, but you can specify the prefix at the end, and get purely numeric suffixes if you want:

```
split -d -l 100 file PREFIX
```

This command will make files `PREFIX01`, `PREFIX02`, and so on. The [`-d` option is a GNU extension](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split), so it isn't supported on all systems.  In that case, or alternatively, you can rename them with a simple shell loop after the fact - it always generates filenames that sort in order.

Comment: Wow! I wasn't expecting such a simple answer. I was completely unaware of the `split` command.
Thank you so very much!

Comment: Is it possible to split one file among 4 files 3 rows at a time? The rub is that the orig file may contain anywhere from 0 rows up to 45, but always divisible by 3.

Comment: @Emile I'm not sure, you should [ask a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).